# Does Google Play Store allow different versions on different tracks to be updated interchangeably?

Tags: android, google-play, publish, google-play-console

The scenario for this problem is as follows:

I have an app that will no longer support certain lower API versions of Android.

However, the previous users in those lower API versions will still need bug fix support for a little while on app version `1xx` (versions from `100` to `199`), for example.

On top of that, the newer version (`200+` for example) will need to be released before support for those versions `1xx` is terminated.

So, in this example, app versions `100` to `199` support Android 7 to 14 while versions `200+` will only support Android 11 to 14.

---

What I am trying to find out is if the following is possible to do in Google Play:

- Keep updating versions `1xx` on release channel (public releases) while at the same time releasing the newer version `2xx` on the beta channel only

So if I have version `129` in release channel and `207` on beta, and I need to update version `130` on release channel only, and not do anything on the beta channel that has the `207` version

Likewise, if I have version `130` in release channel and `207` on beta, and I need to update version `208` on beta channel only, and not do anything on the release channel that has the `130` version

---

I tried finding anything if this is possible in Google Play documentation, but there was nothing as far as I could see.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, it is possible.

For you to update the version on a given channel, you need to upload an app bundle with a version code that is higher than the version code of the last bundle **in that channel**.